# Assigning the same number to multiple enum members

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

[image: Screenshot]

If I assign the same number to the variables in the `enum` structure, which one will it call?

It varies according to the same number of values ​​I give, 2 same value or 3 same value. Sometimes first variable comes back, sometimes last.

Comment: Please post code as *text* rather than images. But fundamentally, if you've got two names for the same value, it's still just one value. There is no "first variable" - perhaps you're referring to the result of calling `ToString()` on the value? If so, the documentation states: "If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return." If that's not what you mean, please clarify your question

Comment: See the duplicate.

Comment: **Third advice:** Keep your variable names English. Use "Months" instead of "Aylar"

**Fourth advice:** Never post your code as screen shot to Stackoverflow. It is not helping us to test it and nobody has time to rewrite your code.

Comment: Thanks for your informations. This was my first question.

Answer (score 0):

**First advice:** Do not use enumeration for months. If you need name of the month you may use something like this

```
// to get the full month name 
string _monthName = date.ToString("MMMM");

// to get the month name for 12th month according to locale
string _monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(12);
```

**Second Advice:** Prefer to use unique values for your enumerations. Otherwise you can only use them one way to resolve it. You may resolve value form string but if you have repeated values it is not possible to resolve string representation from value.

Comment: "Always" is a stretch here, I think (as it usually is, IMO - I can't think of many pieces of advice which really have no situations where it doesn't make sense to violate that advice). There are times where it makes sense to overload the naming - and that's fine so long as you know the implications. You can write code to canonicalize the "value to string" conversion if you need to.

Comment: That's better. Although I'd also suggest following .NET naming conventions for variables (`monthName` instead of `month_name`). I'd remove the third and fourth bits as they're not really about the question topic - better as comments on the question IMO.